# How should I cluster items into an ordered collection that makes sense graphically?

Tags: .net, algorithm, puzzle

I've got an an application wherein I will be provided with an unordered collection of items (objects that can basically be represented as rectangles) and need to put them into a larger rectangular shape (a cluster) based off of their physical location. There may be more than one cluster of items, and some items may be in a cluster by themselves.

Each item knows which item is to its right (if any) and which item is below it (if any). Thus the items could be placed in a [`Directed Graph`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(data_structure)) and traversed.

How can I display all of the items graphically? If I put the items in a `Graph`, how should I traverse it?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? If you want to cluster things then you need to explain what are the clustering criteria. If you want to put things into a datastructure, you need to explain what operations you want it to support efficiently. Either way, the answer most likely includes some kind of spatial subdivision datastructure.

Comment: @Ants: The clustering criteria is that each cluster contains one or more items, and all items with neighbors are in that cluster. The problem that I am trying to solve is how to visually display items when they present themselves in a non-visual manner. (Specifically, these are modules of an LED sign that work together to create one or more sign faces [clusters].)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good use case for the PR QuadTree: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/QuadTree.aspx

Comment: From playing with the QuadTree, it doesn't seem to match my application, but it is a good link and is new subject matter to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best solution I've come up with so far is to use the [GraphSharp](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com) library, although I haven't yet figured out how to customize the look of the `Vertices` (items) in the graph.